# How to add a to the absolute value of b without call abs

Tags: python, function

I'm having a little problem defining a function. I'm trying to add a to the absolute value of b without calling abs

```
from operator import add, sub
def a_plus_absolute_b(a, b):
    """Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs."""
    if b < 0:
        op = add(a, (b * -1))
    else:
        op = add(a, b)
    return op(a, b)
```

Comment: @Daniel: Because it's homework.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to import `add()` for this.

Why don't you simply do

```
def a_plus_absolute_b(a, b):
    """Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs."""
    if b < 0:
        result = a - b
    else:
        result = a + b
    return result
```

Comment: I would have just said `return a - b if b < 0 else a + b`

Answer (score 5):

The solution you're looking for, which you're overlooking because you're obsessed with the idea of "negative", is as follows:

```
from operator import add, sub
def a_plus_absolute_b(a, b):
    """Return a+abs(b), but without calling abs."""
    if b < 0:
        op = sub
    else:
        op = add
    return op(a, b)
```

Note how the parens, used to call a function, are only in the last line.